# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/volley/VolleyLog;

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, module, aar

I have created new android project and inside the project created new library module (network).

Now we have app (default module) and network module.

Inside the network module I have volley dependency which is not there in app module.

Created Kotlin class and define this method in Network Module

**/* Network Module */**

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'

    // Volley Network
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

// VolleyUtils.kt

```
 class VolleyUtils {
     fun enableLog() {
            VolleyLog.DEBUG = true
     }
 }
```

Create AAR from network module and place inside the app module

**/* App Module */**

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.base"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'

    implementation(name: 'volleynetwork-release', ext: 'aar')
//    implementation project(':volleynetwork')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

// MainActivity.kt

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
       super.onreate(saveInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       //access method in network module
       VolleyUtils().enableLog()
    }
}
```

Compiled Successfully. But, @Runtime result in exception

Result :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/volley/VolleyLog;
    at com.test.volleynetwork.VolleyUtils.enableLog(VolleyUtils.kt:8)
    at com.test.base.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2932)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1817)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6746)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.volley.VolleyLog" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.base-LKNAponHFP3pH9lW8RU9sQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.base-LKNAponHFP3pH9lW8RU9sQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
```

So, the issue occur only when AAR generated otherwise it's working fine
Please guide me where i am goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

add the following in your app's build.gradle:

```
implementation(project(":Name_of_your_network_module"))
```

NOTE: keep ":" in the beginning.

## EDIT

Try to change the **`Volley`** dependencies in **`Network Module`** from **`implementation`** to **`api`**.

Comment: Hi Karan, I got this error only when I am accessing that method when it was in AAR. otherwise, It was working fine.

Comment: You are trying to access VolleyLog class from :APP module. Pretty sure you said implementation in the network build gradle as thats why its not getting exposed to the app module. Post your build gradle files.

Comment: Bro I have update both default app module and network module gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Add you aar, Import network module aar then
Just add volley dependency again to your base project in build.gradle app module.

dependencies {

....

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

}

Because of aar may be some dependency files of HurlStack was removed